# Whats the error in this code

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void inputArray(double [], int );

void printArray(double [] ,int);

int main()

{

    double rainfall[5];

    rainfall[0]=1;
    rainfall[1]=6;
    rainfall[2]=9;
    rainfall[3]=23;
    rainfall[4]=67;

    printArray(rainfall,5);
    inputArray(rainfall,5);
}

                void printArray(double array[],int size)
   {

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        cout<< "Rainfall is";
        cout << array[i] <<endl;
}}


void inputArray(double array[], int size)
{

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        cout << "Enter the Rainfall:";
        cin >> array[i] << endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: `cin >> array[i] << endl;` why are you trying to send `endl` to `cin`? You cant do this.

Comment: Submitting a relatively large homework-style program without explaining what the problem is as well as demonstrating no effort to solve it yourself is not considered appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this:

```
cin >> foo << endl;
```

Near the last line of your code, it looks like you're trying to do something like:

1. Get some input and put it in array[i]
2. Echo the input and a new line?

You should do it like:

```
cin >> array[i];
cout << array[i] << endl;
```

Remember, `cin >> foo` means "take some *input* from the console and put it in foo," and `cout << foo` means "*output* foo to the console."

Comment: Can you explain why you can not do this.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can't **cin** "endl", you shoul **cout** it;
2. You asking user for entering values, but you don't use it.